# jquery datepicker does not show in a invisible asp:panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a asp:panel that by default is invisible.
this panel is a overlay window that take some inputs.

i want to add jquery datepicker in a text box in this panel 
but because this panel is invisible by default and visible after a click on a button 
datepicker does not work ..
when i change visibility of panel every thing works fine!

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function date () {

        $(".test").datepicker(
            { showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: '../Script/jquery.ui.datepicker1.8.14-cc/styles/images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true});


    });
</script>
```

Comment: By Invisible you mean Panel.Visible = false?

Comment: @ Andrey Borisko :yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

In the case you are changing Visibility server-side, you need to leave it Visible and control such things using css `display:none` because it actually removes your panel contents from DOM.

Or if I'm not mistaken you can just do this in WebForms:

```
Panel.CssClass += "hide-me"
```

and css class should be:

```
.hide-me {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Dear Andrey, i test this , use display:none and display:inline from code behind to visible and hide my asp:panel but problem doesn't solved.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur do to ajax script manager and updatepanel
when i remove ajax script manager every thing work properly 
i have to register datepicker script in page load by use :
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
now i try to solve my problem with this...

Answer (score 0):

i change my script to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) 
    {
        $(".test").datepicker(
            { showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: '../Script/jquery.ui.datepicker1.8.14-cc/styles/images/calendar.png',
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });

    }

</script>
```

so now every thing is ok!